# Extract header data from instances of string pattern in list, where there are repeated occurrences

Tags: r, regex, text-extraction, tibble

I have a certain list:

```
lst <- list(A=c('aa', 'bb', 'cc'), B=c('ee', 'ff' ,'gg') ,C=c('aa', 'bb', 'bbc', 'dd'))

$A
[1] "aa" "bb" "cc"

$B
[1] "ee" "ff" "gg"

$C
[1] "aa"  "bb"  "bbc" "dd"
```

I use `str_extract_all` to collect part of the data that fits a certain pattern.

```
> data <- str_extract_all(lst, 'bb') %>% unlist() %>% compact()

[1] "bb" "bb" "bb"
```

I'd like to display the result on a tibble, indicating the source (i.e. list header) from which the pattern is extracted. This gives the following error due to repeated occurrence of "bb" in $C.

```
> tibble(data = data, src = names(lst[grep('bb', lst)]))
錯誤: Column `src` must be length 1 or 3, not 2
```

The code works fine when there are no repeated occurrences.

```
> lst <- list(A=c('aa', 'bb', 'cc'), B=c('ee', 'ff', 'gg') ,C=c('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'))

$A
[1] "aa" "bb" "cc"

$B
[1] "ee" "ff" "gg"

$C
[1] "aa" "bb" "cc" "dd"

> data <- str_extract_all(lst, 'bb') %>% unlist() %>% compact()
> tibble(data = data, src = names(lst[grep('bb', lst)]))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
   data   src
  <chr> <chr>
1    bb     A
2    bb     C
```

How can I code to avoid the error?

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
   data   src
  <chr> <chr>
1    bb     A
2    bb     C
3    bbc    C
```

---

While working on my solution, I think my question ultimately boils down to this:

```
> pattern <- c('bb', 'ee')
> grep(paste(pattern, collapse="|"), lst)
[1] 1 2 3
```

`grep()` tells me that the specific string patterns can be found in the first and third items on my list.

What I would rather like to do is to get `grep()` to repeat the item number whenever a recurrence of the pattern(s) is found.

```
[1] 1 2 3 3
```

I should be able to use this pattern to generate a vector of sources and `cbind()` with my `str_extract()` results later:

```
> rslt <- tibble(data = c('bb', 'ee', 'bb', 'bbc'), src = c( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
   data   src
  <chr> <chr>
1    bb     A
2    ee     B
3    bb     C
4   bbc     C
```

---

**SOLUTION:**

Here's my own solution to the problem.

```
lst <- list(A=paste0('aa', str_dup("xy", 50), "bb", str_dup("ov", 50), "bb", str_dup("nm", 50), 'cc'), B=paste0('ee', 'ff' ,'gg') ,C=paste0('aa', str_dup("qed", 50), "bb", str_dup("sh", 50), 'bbc', 'dd'))

x <- str_count(lst, "bb") #Count instances to indicate repeats
x <- x[x != 0] #Remove the 0s
src.id <- mapply(rep, grep('bb', lst), x) %>% unlist() #Repeat source index to generate source vector
rslt <- tibble(str = str_extract_all(lst, "..bb..") %>% unlist() %>% compact(), src = names(lst[src.id]))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
     str   src
   <chr> <chr>
1 xybbov     A
2 ovbbnm     A
3 edbbsh     C
4 shbbcd     C
```

This works even when the repeated pattern is embedded in a sub-string (as above).

Comment: @MichaelChirico and Sotos, because the length of each element in my actual data is much longer than the example I gave, I would very much like to use str_extract() or something similar to filter out a specific string pattern for analysis. Using grep() alone extracts the whole chunk, which is not very useful.

Comment: Add an example to demonstrate what you mean so we can edit our answers accordingly.

Comment: On my solution, just add the new pattern in `filter`, i.e. `filter(grepl('bb|aa', v1))` and you will get desired result

Comment: @Sotos, please refer to my edited question above.

Comment: I m sorry I don't get it. How do you convert `xyxyxyxyxyxy...` to `yxybbxyx`?

Comment: @Sotos, please refer to this code above: `lst <- list(A=c('aa', paste0(str_dup("xy", 100), "bb", str_dup("xy", 100)), 'cc'), B=c('ee', 'ff' ,'gg') ,C=c('aa', paste0(str_dup("qed", 100), "bb", str_dup("xy", 100)), 'ccbbcc', 'dd'))` The pattern "...bb..." is embedded in xyxyxyxyxyxy... I just want to view the part of the string containing "...bb...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this in base R.

```
# get the matching values for each list element
tmp <- lapply(lst, function(x) x[grep("bb", x)])

# build a data.frame
data.frame(val=unlist(tmp, use.names=FALSE), src=rep(names(tmp), lengths(tmp)))
```

`unlist` returns a vector from the selected items and use.names=FALSE allows `data.frame` to return the standard row names rather than the names that would be produced by `unlist`. The second argument to `data.frame` repeats the names of the elements in tmp to match the matched elements.

This returns

```
  val src
1  bb   A
2  bb   C
3 bbc   C
```

---

for longer strings, where you only want to match the surrounding 3 characters on either side, you could replace `x[grep(...)]` with `regmatches(regexpr)` like this:

```
tmp <- lapply(lst, function(x) regmatches(x, regexpr("(...)?bb(...)?", x)))
# unchanged from above
data.frame(val=unlist(tmp, use.names=FALSE), src=rep(names(tmp), lengths(tmp)))
```

For the second example, this returns

```
       val src
1 yxybbxyx   A
2 qedbbxyx   C
3       bb   C
```

Comment: Same issue here, as communicated with @Sotos above. If my pattern is embedded in a long string like this `paste0(str_dup("xy", 100), "bb", str_dup("xy", 100))`, it would not be very convenient for observation.

Comment: Does this mean that you want to extract a substring around the matching pattern?

Comment: Yes, I guess so.

Answer (score 1):

This turned into a bit of a kludge, but the following works:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(lst, function(x) data.table(mtch = grep('bb', x, value = TRUE))),
          idcol = 'where')
#    where mtch
# 1:     A   bb
# 2:     C   bb
# 3:     C  bbc
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` idea,

```
library(tidyverse)

unlist(lst) %>% 
    data.frame() %>% 
    rename('v1' = '.') %>% 
    rownames_to_column('v2') %>% 
    filter(grepl('bb', v1)) %>% 
    mutate(v2 = sub('\\d+', '', v2))
```

which gives,

> ```
>   v2  v1
> 1  A  bb
> 2  C  bb
> 3  C bbc
> ```